# Error during installing PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

During installing PostgreSQL I got this message:

```
postgresql-9.5 (9.5.5-0ubuntu0.16.04) wird eingerichtet ...
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Creating new cluster 9.5/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.5/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
  locale de_DE.UTF-8
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5432
```

What should I do?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/1545904

Comment: Just ran into this as well...it is a warning not an error, so nothing to do.  If you want to silence it, change `{` to `\{` and `}` to `\}` in /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.